# Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Tags: android

I am new to android world.

I have made an application of a user registration. It was working fine. but when i tried to add a spinner to my activity file, it was showing an error in avd, like,

> The Application Registration (Process com.students) has stopped
>   unexpectedly. please try again

comes.

and my log cat is showing the error

> "11-12 10:42:06.816: E/dalvikvm(313): Unable to open stack trace file
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied"

What is actually that error? How can i get rid of that?

Comment: Show the code that you are using and also the complete stack-trace.

Comment: Your application crashed due to some other reason (bug in code maybe). You can ignore the "Unable to open stack trace.." error, it is not the reason for your application crash. Please post the complete stack-trace and relevant portion of your application code.

Comment: You also may get this error if you don't setup the SDCard on your emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a problem I had when I was new to Android.  Then I learned that the message about being unable to write to traces.txt was not the actual problem with the program.

The solution to this problem is thus to find and correct the actual (unrelated to this message) reason the program is crashing.  Then this message (which reflects a configuration problem in the crash reporting system) will no longer occur.

Comment: This should be a comment. I doesn't show how you fixed your error.

Comment: This really is the correct answer - however I'm somewhat uncomfortable with the fact that after a moderator's edit what is currently showing is my previously fully disclosed re-write of it, without the original text (from the question asker themselves) which I had carefully retained when I edited it.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to access the external storage. Make sure you have necessary permission defined in your Manifest file. This can be done by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the write permission error for one of my test devices, Android 2.3.6

Comment: This answer is **utterly incorrect and quite bad advice**. First, the problem is with android itself, not the application program. But even if it were the program being written, this answer is obviously wrong as **/data is not an External Storage path**.

Answer (score 4):

This error has nothing to do with your app. Its referring stack trace file that gets generated when your app crashes so the user can report it to the publisher. The reason you are seeing that error is that your app was not installed through the android market so it does not have permission to write to that file. Errors that your app is generating during debug can be seen in LogCat and a stack trace will be dumped there describing the error.

Comment: This answer is basically correct in that the particular message indicates a problem in the failure reporting mechanism, but not the actual *reason why something crashed*.  The cause of the crash (if it is indeed a crash of an app being developed, and not a coincidently timed crash of something else) should be determined with logcat and/or other debugging tools and fixed.  I'm less certain about the offered explanation linkage the missing permission to not being a market install (rather than a simple misconfiguration of the installed Android build) - any references on that theory?

Comment: In particular, on current devices, this file is world writable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am voting this answer up as I just ran into this issue myself and after some investigation found out that the reason for the failure was indeed because the app was untrusted (not coming from the Play Store). This is a policy enforced at the kernel level. I had to look at the kernel logs to see it. So Sani's answer is pretty accurate, although  not  backed by any source/proof as you mentioned :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with market or non-market apps.  That only concerns installation - once installed they are identical.

Answer (score 1):

The operation on /data/anr/traces.txt need root or system user chmod.
Ref `ActivityManagerService#dumpStackTraces` code:

```
public static File dumpStackTraces(boolean clearTraces, ArrayList<Integer> firstPids,
        ProcessCpuTracker processCpuTracker, SparseArray<Boolean> lastPids, String[] nativeProcs) {
    String tracesPath = SystemProperties.get("dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file", null);
    if (tracesPath == null || tracesPath.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File tracesFile = new File(tracesPath);
    try {
        if (clearTraces && tracesFile.exists()) tracesFile.delete();
        tracesFile.createNewFile();
        FileUtils.setPermissions(tracesFile.getPath(), 0666, -1, -1); // -rw-rw-rw-
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Slog.w(TAG, "Unable to prepare ANR traces file: " + tracesPath, e);
        return null;
    }

    dumpStackTraces(tracesPath, firstPids, processCpuTracker, lastPids, nativeProcs);
    return tracesFile;
}
```

And I handle the problem in the shell as following.
`adb root`
`adb shell touch /data/anr/traces.txt`
`adb shell kill -3 ${APP_PID}`