# '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

Tags: php, android, mysql, http

I have been trying out the tutorial shown on various websites on connecting a MySQL database using php to android. I dont know whats wrong with my code below. Can anyone tell me what i need to do.

**ihave this problems : Unfortunately , city has stopped**

IN LOGCAT : 01-17 02:57:18.790: E/dalvikvm(325): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

This is my php code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","???????????","......;");
mysql_select_db("???????????");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

city.java

```
package com.android.City;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class city extends ListActivity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
//http post
try{
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.estm2011.org/check.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
//convert response to string
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
//paring data
String login;
String pass;
try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      JSONObject json_data=null;
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             login=json_data.getString("LOGIN");
             pass=json_data.getString("PASSWORD");
         }
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.City"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".CityActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your log from DDMS for clarify your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102719/unable-to-open-stack-trace-file-data-anr-traces-txt-permission-denied)

Comment: This is not the actual problem in your program, but merely an annoying configuration bug in the crash reporting subsystem.  Use logcat to find and fix the actual problem, and you will stop seeing this on account of your program, though it can still occur when other programs crash.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `adb` shell to inside folder `/data/anr` to check the your file permission.

if permission is root, maybe you need run as the root user or root your device.

Comment: i use windows and i login root

Comment: Not the same as root on the device.

Answer (score -1):

Your application is NOT considered root, you cannot view it from an app's perspective you have to make the file viewable by the app layer also known as "user." Or if you wish, you may have the same PID as the System. Whichever comes first.

Comment: You need to look up how linux manages permissions. This will guide you, being that you are root on your device you can change the permission to suit your need.

Comment: i use windows vista not linux

Comment: i use ddms file explorer but i cant see file traces.txt

Comment: data/anr have permission drwxrwx--x

Comment: you need to change the permission of that file.. by adbing into the phone (adb shell) and navigating to the directory and changing the permission.

Comment: i cant i have this probleme su:uid 10016 not allowed  to su

Comment: then your device isn't rooted.